# Generating Datamatrix with iTextSharp using multithreading causes crash

Tags: c#, multithreading, itext, barcode, datamatrix

I'm getting a crash in my code when generating a datamatrix for a label. After a lot of testing, I've determined it's due to multi-threading, however I cannot determine why.

I'm using iTextSharp v5.5.13.2(Nuget package). Code that will replicate the error is below:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
            {
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix dataMatrix = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix();

                dataMatrix.Height = 18;
                dataMatrix.Width = 18;
                dataMatrix.ForceSquareSize = true;

                dataMatrix.Generate("TestData");
            });
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

This is the error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix.B256Encodation(byte[], int, int, byte[], int, int, int, int, int)
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix.GetEncodation(byte[], int, int, byte[], int, int, int, bool)
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix.Generate(byte[], int, int)
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix.Generate(string)
    DataAccessTesting.Form1.Function1_Click.AnonymousMethod__59_0(object) in Form1.cs
    System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool)
    System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
    System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

If I remove the multithreading, it runs perfectly fine. So this code works:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix dataMatrix = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix();

            dataMatrix.Height = 18;
            dataMatrix.Width = 18;
            dataMatrix.ForceSquareSize = true;

            dataMatrix.Generate("TestData");
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

I'm using multi threading in the application to generate all the labels and immediately start printing them, even while other labels are still still generating. Forcing them to wait until each of the others has finished processing will significantly slow down the application, so removing the multithreading is a last resort option.

How can I prevent this error from occurring without removing multi threading?

EDIT:
I keep getting told I don't have the complete code. I tested again, and by putting the code I added into a button event, I can replicate the error. Here's a screenshot.
[image: Complete code for the error]

Comment: Tried in a Winforms app and a Console app, with and without threading, could not reproduce the error. Are you sure you're showing all the relevant code?

Comment: @evilmandarine Yeah, I'm certain. I put this code in a button event from a WinForms application. I'm probably going to delete this question, as we used a different library that appears to work. And as a plus, now we don't need to pay for a license when we roll it out.

Comment: @NicholaiRen - The code is not complete. For this error to occur you must be using `i` inside the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` lambda. Your issue is you're not capturing the local variable. You'd have to post the complete code to get an answer though.

Comment: @Enigmativity I may be missing something really obvious. I double checked when I posted. I can copy and paste the code from this question into a winforms project, link it to a button, and run it, and the error occurs. I don't have time at the moment to check it again, but what do you mean by the code isn't complete? Do you need the whole form code?

Comment: @NicholaiRen - I think you need to check if `iTextSharp` is thread-safe for multiple instances on different threads, but otherwise the code is incomplete.

Comment: @NicholaiRen - Sorry, I just saw the screenshot. Clearly your code is complete, so that means that there must be some `static` state in the component that is preventing multiple instances running in different threads. There's an inherent race condition.

Comment: @Enigmativity Strangely, I could now reproduce the issue. There are indeed static fields: `private static int[][] f; private static int[][] switchMode;`. Making these not static and making some methods not static in the class solves the issue: https://pastebin.com/PFnqBYQa. Not sure I can post this as an answer. Also this other lib is old but works quite well: https://github.com/msmuelle-astrumit/DataMatrix.net.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I thought I was going insane because it just wasn't working, I didn't even think to look inside the iTextSharp code. In my mind, since I was initializing the class INSIDE of the loop, then it should be thread safe. Static methods didn't occur to me. Thanks. On another note, kinda funny, the Datamatrix.Net is the library we switched to yesterday.

Comment: @NicholaiRen - The evils of `static`!

Comment: @evilmandarine - Your comment is almost a complete answer. The value here is that the external library contained `static` state. Put that in your answer and link to the repo and that's good for me. I'll up-vote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decompiling the `BarcodeDatamatrix` in the library confirms that the `Generate` method is not thread-safe, due to the usage of the following fields (*thanks @Enigmativity for the insightful comment*):

```
private static int[][] f;
private static int[][] switchMode;
```

The class at the following location makes these fields (as well as other methods that use them) not `static`, fixing the thread-safety issue. Important: if the library/NuGet (actually this class) gets updated, this may need to be done again should you want to use the latest version:
https://pastebin.com/PFnqBYQa

**Alternative solution**
Use the `DataMatrix.net` library available [here](https://github.com/msmuelle-astrumit/DataMatrix.net) or [here](http://datamatrixnet.sourceforge.net/) (old library, not sure which one is better).

**Additional information**
I also tested ZXing.NET but FNC1 characters (ex. group separator `\x1D`) were not working properly. This works fine with the above library.

**Code samples** (for alternative libraries):

```
// ZXING: FNC1 not working
//var dm = new BarcodeWriter
//{
//    Format = BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX,
//    Options =
//    {
//        GS1Format = true,
//        PureBarcode = true
//    }
//};

//var gs1Code = "0107612345678900171" + "\x1D" + "00503";
//var bmp = dm.Write(gs1Code);
//return bmp;


// Datamatrix.NET
var imageEncoder = new DmtxImageEncoder();
var options = new DmtxImageEncoderOptions
{
    ModuleSize = 8,
    MarginSize = 30,
    BackColor = Color.White,
    ForeColor = Color.Black,
    Scheme = DmtxScheme.DmtxSchemeAsciiGS1
};

var barcode = txt1.Text.Length == 13 
    ? "0" + txt1.Text
    : txt1.Text;

return imageEncoder.EncodeImage("01" + barcode
                              + "10" + txt2.Text + "\x1D"
                              + "21" + txt3.Text
                              , options);
```